# Delayed read performance when using navigator.serial for serial communication

Tags: javascript, serial-port, chromium, navigator

I've been trying out the web serial API in chrome (https://web.dev/serial/) to do some basic communication with an Arduino board. I've noticed quite a substantial delay when reading data from the serial port however. This same issue is present in some demos, but not all.

For instance, using the [WebSerial](https://webserial.io/) demo linked towards the bottom has a near instantaneous read:

[image]

While using the [Serial Terminal](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/serial-terminal/) example results in a read delay. (note the write is triggered at the moment of a character being entered on the keyboard):

[image]

WebSerial being [open source](https://github.com/williamkapke/webserial) allows for me to check for differences between my own implementation, however I am seeing performance much like the second example.

As for the relevant code:

```
this.port = await navigator.serial.requestPort({ filters });

await this.port.open({ baudRate: 115200, bufferSize: 255, dataBits: 8, flowControl: 'none', parity: 'none', stopBits: 1 });
this.open = true;
this.monitor();

private monitor = async () => {
    const dataEndFlag = new Uint8Array([4, 3]);
    while (this.open && this.port?.readable) {
        this.open = true;
        const reader = this.port.readable.getReader();
        try {
            let data: Uint8Array = new Uint8Array([]);
            while (this.open) {
                const { value, done } = await reader.read();
                if (done) {
                    this.open = false;
                    break;
                }
                if (value) {
                    data = Uint8Array.of(...data, ...value);
                }
                if (data.slice(-2).every((val, idx) => val === dataEndFlag[idx])) {
                    const decoded = this.decoder.decode(data);
                    this.messages.push(decoded);
                    data = new Uint8Array([]);
                }
            }
        } catch {
        }
    }
}

public write = async (data: string) => {
    if (this.port?.writable) {
        const writer = this.port.writable.getWriter();
        await writer.write(this.encoder.encode(data));
        writer.releaseLock();
    }
}
```

The equivalent WebSerial code can be found [here](https://github.com/williamkapke/webserial/blob/main/src/stores/connection.js#L97), this is pretty much an exact replica. From what I can observe, it seems to hang at `await reader.read();` for a brief period of time.

This is occurring both on a Windows 10 device and a macOS Monterey device. The specific hardware device is an Arduino Pro Micro connected to a USB port.

Has anyone experienced this same scenario?

Update: I did some additional testing with more verbose logging. It seems that the time between the write and read is exactly 1 second *every time*.

Comment: Clarify what your underlying host OS and "*serial port*" hardware are (e.g. USB CDC ACM or USB -to-TTL-UART adapter or a real RS-232 UART).

Comment: Host devices are both Windows 10 and macOS Monterey. Hardware is an Arduino Pro Micro connected via USB. Updated the post to include this detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the delay may result from SerialEvent() in your arduino script: set Serial.setTimeout(1);
This means 1 millisecond instead of default 1000 milliseconds.

Comment: Seems this was the issue. Appending a newline character to the write also seems to work. Thanks!